# How do you cross-reference Google Places results with other 3rd party data providers? (Yelp, Foursquare, etc.)

Tags: geolocation, google-places-api

Does the Google Places API have any built-in support for cross-referencing the returned places with other data providers (Yelp, Foursquare, etc.)? For example Factual has erected the Crosswalk standard to map the IDs of the results across various different data providers. I don't see Google Places on the [supported providers](http://developer.factual.com/display/docs/Places+API+-+Supported+Crosswalk+Services) though.
How would you go about augmenting information from other data providers (or with your own data) if using Google Places as your places provider?

Comment: The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris. I have filed a feature request as you said. Could you also give some insight into why Google has chosen to not erect/adopt a standard for cross-referencing? I see this as a huge deal-breaker for anybody wanting to integrate with a modern places data provider. If you're stuck with one data source the scenarios the API can support become very limited (basic business directory services, essentially).

Comment: @Marchy if you've found solution then please share it with us all

Comment: Is this crosswalk really work. I wanting the yelp id and google place id from factual api. In document they are telling us that they are providing the data related to yelp and google place

Answer (score 1):

Also Yelp won't let you merge results as part of their T&Cs, understandably but sadly.